# Exception dispatching input event. and LruCache

Tags: java, android, apk-expansion-files

I have a problem when I scroll my `ListView`. After a while I get the errors in logcat, but I dodn't know what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
public class ListFeedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Feed> feeds;
    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListFeedAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Feed> feeds) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.feeds = feeds;
         // Bitmap Cache
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
        mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
            }

        };

    }


    public int getCount() {
        return feeds.size();
    }


     // Permet de retourner un objet contenu dans la liste


    public Object getItem(int index) {
        return feeds.get(index);
    }


    public long getItemId(int index) {
        return this.feeds.get(index).getId();

    }



     // * Voici la partie la plus complexe de la classe




    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        FeedView fv=null;

    if (convertView == null) {
            fv = new FeedView();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_view, null);
             fv.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            fv.description = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);            
            fv.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            fv.pubDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pub_date);
            convertView.setTag(fv);

        } else {
            fv = (FeedView) convertView.getTag();
        }    

     Bitmap bitmap = mMemoryCache.get(feeds.get(position).getImage());

     if (bitmap != null) {
         fv.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     } else {

         ThumbnailTask getbitmap=new ThumbnailTask(fv.image, feeds.get(position).getImage(), position);
         getbitmap.execute();


     }



        fv.description.setText(feeds.get(position).getDescription());
        fv.pubDate.setText(feeds.get(position).getPubDate());
        fv.title.setText(feeds.get(position).getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }




    public static int getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            return bitmap.getByteCount();
        } else {
            return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
        }
    }



    public class ThumbnailTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bitmap> {


         private  ImageView bmImage;
         private String url;
         private int pst;

         public ThumbnailTask(ImageView image,String url,int pst) {
                this.bmImage=image; 
                this.url=url;
                this.pst=pst;
                bmImage.setTag(pst);
                bmImage.setImageBitmap(null);
          }



        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {



             URL url=null;
             HttpURLConnection connection;
             InputStream input;
            Bitmap img=null;

                try {
                      url = new URL(this.url);
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.connect();
                     input = connection.getInputStream();
                   img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    input.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("img", "Error getting bitmap"); 
                }           
                mMemoryCache.put(this.url, img);

            return img;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
             super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
             if(bitmap != null && ((Integer)this.bmImage.getTag()) == this.pst)
                         this.bmImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }    
}
```

And this is the LogCat data:

```
09-06 21:29:17.139: E/InputEventReceiver(2216): Exception dispatching input event.
09-06 21:29:17.209: D/AndroidRuntime(2216): Shutting down VM
09-06 21:29:17.259: W/dalvikvm(2216): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a9fba8)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216): Process: com.test.fragmenttest, PID: 2216
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216): java.lang.NullPointerException: key == null
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.util.LruCache.get(LruCache.java:113)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at com.test.fragmenttest.ListFeedAdapter.getView(ListFeedAdapter.java:113)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2240)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:655)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5136)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3236)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3580)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3424)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
09-06 21:29:17.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
......
```

Comment: You're calling `mMemoryCache.get` with a `null` argument. There is a item that returns `null` for `feeds.get(position).getImage()`. Also the error message describes this quite well with line numbers and everything. So pro tip for the future, programming includes debugging which requires reading error messages and stack traces.

Comment: Yes I know that..How can I solve this ??

Comment: Look into why `feeds.get(position).getImage()` is returning `null`. We can't guess that and the Feed class is not included in your code. So you'll have to look at that yourself.